# CSS How to use margins with different divs

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry

Edit: Added Javascript and Masonry tags. I've been looking at masonry and all my modules are the same size so I'm not sure how masonry can help me as I'm not trying to get different size elements to line up. I'm still looking through masonry tutorials as it's a little confusing at the moment. If this is the fix I apologize for adding the additional tags.

I'm creating three divs offline, issues, and then go. I'm taking what I'm calling modules and placing them within these three divs. When I place more than 3 modules they create another row. Unfortunately my titles don't move with the modules and I have to manually go in and change the margin-top to line everything up. I'm not sure how to make it to where the issue rows will change based on how many modules are in there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="grid_17">
        <div id="offlinetitle">
<p>System is Offline</p>
           </div>

        <div id="issuestitle">
    <p>System is partially offline or experiencing issues</p>
        </div>

        <div id="issuescontents">
             <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="AccessModal" data-animation="none">
            <div class="grid_3">
                    <p id="contexttitle">Access</p>
                <p id="accesssubmenu">Last Update: 08/30/2013 5:00pm</p>
                </div>
             </a> 

<div id="AccessModal" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Access</h1>
        <p>This is text to describe something>
                    <p4>Last Update: 08/30/2013 5:00pm</p4>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>   
                       </div>    

        <div id="gotitle">
            <p>All systems go</p>
        </div>            

    </div>
```

My CSS is as follows grid 17 is the parent container that everything is in then the last container is the actual modules.

```
.grid_17{

} 

#offlinetitle{
color:#FFF;
font-size:25px;
background:#F00;
height: 35px;
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
}

#issuestitle{
color:#FFF;
font-size:25px;
background:#FC0;
height: 35px;
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
margin-top:15px;
}

#gotitle{
color:#FFF;
font-size:25px;
background:#093;
height: 35px;
text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
margin-top:535px;
}
.container_24 .grid_3 {
  width: 213px;
  background:#CCC;
  height:55px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

If more information is needed please let me know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap each "module" (title and contents) in it's own div and then float this parent div to the left.  Something like this:

```
<div class="grid_17">
    <div>
        <div id="offlinetitle">...</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="issuestitle">...</div>
        <div id="issuescontents">...</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="gotitle">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS similar to:

```
.grid_17 { width: 300px; }
.grid_17 > div { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

Note about clearfix: If you display anything after the `grid_17` div, you'll also need to clear the float.  I won't go into depth here, but you might want to look up the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) class.

Comment: I tried to do this and had to keep changing the height. It did the same thing similar to when I did margin-top to each of the divs except this would apply the height to all 3 at the same time. I need them to change when more/less modules are applied.

Comment: What you are trying to do can't be done with pure CSS.  To get variable height elements organized into rows, you need to use either a table (where you manually start a new row) or with a framework like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: I added javascript and masonry to the tags. I'm looking at masonry tutorials but a lot of them seem to be getting different size elements to line up where all my modules are the same size. I apologize if masonry is the fix I'm still reading up on it as it's a little confusing to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do.  The code you posted isn't enough to see the problem.  Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W6zYA/1/ Hopefully this will show what I mean a little better. I just want to move the divs between red, yellow, and green but I want the titles to dynamically move with however many I put in there so for example if there are 3 rows in yellow green will still be 10px below the last div.

Comment: That helps...thanks.  Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9As2/) that I forked. It had 2 issues: `.grid_17 > div` had `height: 10px` specified...that is unnecessary.  And, `#issuestitle` and `#gotitle` should specify `margin-top:10px`.  See my comments in the jsFiddle CSS prefixed with "NPS:".  Let me know if my jsFiddle modifications don't achieve what you want.  Punchline is that the fixed height on the divs was causing the problem.

Comment: I love you, seriously I feel like a dunce! I searched everywhere trying to figure this out. I also checked your website VERY NICE. I hope to be where you're at one day. Would vote up but can't due to not enough reputation. Sorry for my explanations and thank you so much!